# What does &operator mean in overloading

Tags: c++, class, stl, vector, overloading

I am reading a C++ book.
The program tries to make a vector of objects.
Here is the part I do not understand

```
class X {
public:
    X();
    X(int m) {
        temp = x;
    }

    int temp;


    X &operator =(int z) {
        temp = z;
        return *this;
    }

private :
    //            Some functions here
}
```

What does above line mean?
Is this some sort of overloading?
Then how?

Comment: Please check your code. I'm sure the program in that book doesn't look like this, because it won't ever compile.

Comment: I fixed the code up just enough to be palatable

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to assume you have a typo and that the line actually reads:

```
X &operator =(int z) {
```

The `&` means that the return type is a reference; you should read this as function `operator =` that returns a type of `X &`.

Comment: means It a form of operator overload !!

Comment: @RahulRai: As far as I can see, overloading is not involved in this code anywhere.

Comment: @Mooing: It's called "operator overloading" anyways, since you overload the fundamental meaning of `x = y` for your class type.

Answer (score 5):

The meaning might be clearer if you change the spacing slightly:

```
X& operator= (int z)
```

That's an overload of the assignment operator, `operator=`, which takes an `int` argument, and returns a reference to `class X`.

You can use it to assign an integer value to an object:

```
X x;
x = 42; // calls the overloaded operator
```

The return value allows you to chain assignments:

```
X x1,x2;
x1 = x2 = 42;   // equivalent to `x2 = 42; x1 = x2;`
(x1 = x2) = 42; // equivalent to `x1 = x2; x1 = 42;`
```

Comment: Right of course, however this kind of chaining would also work if `operator=` returned by value.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Yes, if the class is copyable.

Comment: A non-copyable class with a copy assignment operator would be weird.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Indeed, but this isn't a copy-assignment operator; it's assigning from a different type. Anyway, for completeness I've added the kind of chaining that does need a non-`const` reference.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your code should look like that:

```
class X {
public:
    int temp;
private :
    //Some functions here 
    X &operator =(int z) 
    {
        temp = z; 
        return *this ;
    }
};
```

And than you deal with `operator=`, not `&operator`

Your `operator =` returns reference to the object it applied to.

Answer (score 1):

It means this: C<sup>*</sup> and C++ allow you to chain assignments like this

```
((x = 4) = 3) = 2;
```

the result of which is that `x` will have the value 2: `x` is first set to 4, then to 3, then to 2 (not very useful it seems, but variations of this can make great shorthand expressions). For this to work, the following needs to happen underneath:

```
x = 4;
X& x2 = x;  // reference to x, so that it can be modified without explicitly writing x
x2 = 3;     // since x2 is just an alias, the variable that's actually changed is x
X& x3 = x2; // again, x2 just refers to x, so now x3 also does
x3 = 2;     // yet again, modifies x
```

*in C, it does of course not work with references, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's `X& operator= (int z)` I think, that is to say a overload of the = operator which takes an int and return a reference to X.

Answer (score 0):

It's the definition of the **assignment operator**: It might look better formatted like this (out-of-line definition):

```
X & X::operator=(int z)
{
    temp = z;
    return *this;
}
```

It allows you to write something like this:

```
X a, b, c(10);
a = b = c;
```

The value of each assignment subexpression is a reference to the assignee.

The operator needs to be *declared* inside the class definition of course:

```
class X
{
public:
    X & operator=(int);
    // ...
};
```